# auto-check radio-button using struts

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, radio-button

I have a jsp page with two radio tags.

The page contains a struts2 form. When I submit the form one of two radio must be automatically checked.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the features of a radio input is that an item in a radio set once selected cannot be deselected except by another member of the set being selected (unlike a checkbox "set"). i.e. if you initialise the page with a selection you can guarantee you will have a value. Does a default value exist you can do this for? Then you can just set `checked="checked"` on that item.

Alternatively you'll just have to add another validation rule in JS and/or the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with:

```
<html:radio property="foo" value="yes"/>
```

this radio tag will show selected (by default) if the method `getFoo()` of the form-bean returns the string "yes".

May be you can use that to link your form submit to your radio tags ?